# Webpack serving old contents in production server

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have react components built using webpack, and the command is

> ./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.config.js
> --mode=production'

Now, it built the bundle successfully without errors.

However, when the built bundle is pushed and pulled in the production server, and opening the app in browser, upon checking the browser's devtools **Sources TAB**, Under webpack, it is serving old contents, 
For example, I updated the `store.js` to remove all console logs, but when I check the store.js in the browser sources tab, console logs are still in there. But opening it in production server using vim editor, all console logs are gone, and I am pretty sure I am looking at the correct file.

Also, I don't think it's a caching issue, since I tried opening it on safari, where it's the first time that the app is opened there.

Please see image below:
[image]

Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");
const UglifyJSPlugin = require("uglifyjs-webpack-plugin");
const eslintFormatter = require("react-dev-utils/eslintFormatter");
const BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require("webpack-bundle-analyzer")
  .BundleAnalyzerPlugin;

module.exports = function (env = {}, mode) {
  const plugins = [];

  if (env["bundle-size"]) {
    plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin());
  }

  if (mode === "production") {
    plugins.push(
      // minify remove some of the dead code
      new UglifyJSPlugin({
        compress: {
          warnings: false,
        },
        output: {
          comments: false,
        },
        sourceMap: true,
      })
    );
  }

  return {
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
      myResults: path.join(__dirname, "./scripts/Results/index.jsx"),
    },
    performance: {
      hints: false,
    },
    stats: {
      modules: false,
    },
    output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, "../html/assets/scripts/react"),
      publicPath: "/assets/scripts/react/",
      filename: "[name].js",
      chunkFilename: "[name].chunk.js",
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: [".js", ".json", ".jsx"],
    },
    module: {
      strictExportPresence: true,
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      ],
    },
    plugins: plugins,browser.
    node: {
      fs: "empty",
      net: "empty",
      tls: "empty",
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: Are you developing a react library or a simple react web?  Is the problem occurring only in prod server or in localhost too? Are you in windows? Could you prepare a mvp or hello world replicating the issue?

Comment: Just a simple react web.  Yes, the issue only occur in prod server, in local, it served the updated code. And I am in Mac, but I think it's not Mac specific problem, my colleague is using windows and is facing same issue

Comment: What os are using in prod and how are you pulling and deploying? Add that info to the question

Comment: It is **Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS**. Deploying is done basically by pushing the bundles and pulling it in prod server.

Comment: In your question im confused about if its dev or production that is showing old code because you say "when the built bundle is pushed and pulled in the production server...[etc]" and then "But opening it in production server using vim editor, all console logs are gone"

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I'm relatively new to webpack, so I might say some nonesense stuff.
But, It's showing old code when I check the webpack in the browser from devtools SOURCES Tab, but when I double check  by using vim editor in the ec2 server if I really did updated the code that's showing the console logs, I can see that it is indeed updated, but not in the browser.

Comment: By pulling, Do you mean git pull the previously pushed bundle? What static server are you using in prod: apache, nginx, haproxy?

Comment: @JRichardsz Yes, that's what I meant by pulling. Server is Apache.

Comment: This could be very wrong -- but it sounds a bit like you are accessing the base server locally, instead of the webpack dev server. Basically, that on your local you might be looking at the version not served from webpack. When you do a prod build locally, it would suddenly update -- as you are seeing

Comment: @adsy Yes, I am fully aware that this is very wrong. This whole application including the server infrastracture is a little bit outdated, and we are in the process of upgrading it. So, we are currently doing prod build locally.

Comment: Makes sense. Could you share your `index.html`?

Comment: Bundle should not be pushed. Could you try to clone only the code and then run the build? Try to build and serve with apache another react app.

Comment: @adsy here's how it's called. 
**<script async src="<?php echo $cdn; ?>assets/scripts/react/myResults.js?v=<?php echo $version ?>"></script>**
.

It is served thru cdn, and the **?v=** query string is needed when we have changes in our scss/images/js/webpack bundled scripts. btw, I also made sure to change the value of **?v=** query string whenever I made changes to these assets so that it's not serving cached assets.

Comment: Php :/ ? React bundle comes with it own index.html. Try to use that instead apache 

Comment: If its served from CDN, im guessing you expect the local webpack dev server to intercept the requests (which is true) because otherwise it wouldn't be up to date without it pushing the new version to the CDN . Coming back to what I previously said, are you 100% sure when devving locally you are using the webpack host/port?

Comment: @adsy Tbh, I'm not really sure what you meant by that. apologies. But it would be great if you could explain further. :D

Comment: No worries. Shortly -- what is the URL you use locally in your browser for local dev?

Comment: @adsy It is http://myapp.local, for production is is https://myapp.com

Comment: Your webpack dev server is probably not on port 80 (which is the default port for HTTP that your browser accesses), it'll be another port. Check the terminal output when you first start webpack dev server -- it prints this here,

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Comment: @JRichardsz yes, it is indeed caching issue. I was wrong, every webpack bundled scripts were served thru cdn, so I changed cdn version parameter and everything worked as expected.

Comment: How did you resolve the caching issue?

Comment: @DilipH Bundled script is served thru a cdn. So, everytime I have webpack related changes, I also need to change the cdn version parameter so it will not serve cached webpack.